# How to make one line coffee script code to multiline?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I tried to use `coffee script` recently, but I have some code like this

```
if userAgent.match(/iPad/i) or userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) or userAgent.match(/iPoid/i) or userAgent.match(/Android/i) or userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) or userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    console.log("This is a mobile device")
else
    console.log("This is not mobile device")
```

So the first line is very long, I want to make it multi-line.Maybe some code like this is much better, but as you know, this is wrong in coffee script.

```
# This is the wrong code
if userAgent.match(/iPad/i) 
    or userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) 
    or userAgent.match(/iPoid/i) 
    or userAgent.match(/Android/i) 
    or userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) 
    or userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    console.log("This is a mobile device")
else
    console.log("This is not mobile device")
```

or some code like this:

```
# This is also wrong
if userAgent.match(/iPad/i) or 
  userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) or 
  userAgent.match(/iPoid/i) or 
  userAgent.match(/Android/i) or 
  userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) or 
  userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    console.log("This is a mobile device")
else
    console.log("This is not mobile device")
```

So any way to correct this?

Comment: Just move your `or` up. End each line with `or` instead of starting with it.

Comment: @AlexPeachey I have tried this, but i can not work

Comment: Define an array of the matches and use a library with an `any` method. Put that into an `isMobile` method. Or even a single regex. Don't try to one-line stuff that should be done a different way.

Comment: @AlexPeachey sorry, I forget to set the indent

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks, you give me a good suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you are much better off if you write the regex like this:

```
if userAgent.match /iPad|iPhone|iPod|Android|IEMobile|BlackBerry/i
```

Comment: *slow clap* I was going to say the same thing